# Autorefresh content

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, dreamweaver

I am using Dreamweaver CS5. I have a SQL database set up with weather descriptions that have been set up to change at a set interval, however they do not refresh on their own unless the page is physically refreshed. I have users that are logged in for hours at a time so that doesn't exactly work.

I know I can fairly easily set a refresh for the entire page, but I'd prefer not to do that.

I would like to just used some kind of javascript or jquery to auto refresh that section of code.

This is the section of code I want to refresh:

```
<?php echo ucfirst($row_Recordset1['description']); ?>
```

I saw this as a solution, but I am not sure how to implement this to work for me, or if there is a better solution all together.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function refreshDiv() {
   gg1.refresh(getRandomInt(0, 100));
}
$(document).ready(function () { setInterval(refreshDiv, 5000); });
</script>
```

Comment: If you use HTML 5, consider to use a Web Worker: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webworkers.asp
Not as easy as CuSS' answer, but it does not affect page performance.

Comment: @gdahl i think his problem is that he isn't using html at all, so he need to create firstly a page that would do something. For me the easiest solution to load data on an interval would do WebSocket, but it isn't quite easy to implement.

Comment: I am using a mixture of php and HTML on the website but the code I want to refresh is strictly php.

Comment: @Cyndi so you have to apply my response on your HTML side. :) Don't forget to mark it as the right question if it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reload the div's content over AJAX. Since you are using jQuery, you can easily do something like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(function(){
        $('#divid').load( '/url' );
    }, 5000);
});
```

You can read more about `.load` [here](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: Using your example how would I define the #Divid? Right now the PHP that I want to refresh is just sitting in the document as <?php echo ucfirst($row_Recordset1['description']); ?>

Comment: For that you must have always 2 pages, one for loading client side, as user interface, and another for presenting data.
The one you load data, you don't need to make changes, you only need to implement that on the one users are visiting.

For example:
* I visit '/page'
  * this page is HTML and it has Javascript and jQuery to load '/page/data'
  * for now one, every X seconds, data will be fetched from '/page/data' instead of '/page'

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

> set timeout()

JavaScript function. And inside that function you need to refresh your div content using jquery Ajax. Script is pretty simple and will give you desired result. For reference check w3schools and jquery  Ajax